# Qt5 use Latin1 instead of Utf8 globally

Tags: c++, qt, utf-8

I ported my project from Qt4 to Qt5 and have now the following problem.

Since Qt5 the constructor `QString(const char*)` assumes that the passed string is Utf8 encoded. That breaks my code because `QStrings` are often converted to `char*` (with `toLatin1()` - for third party library apis) and backwards only with `QString(const char*)` instead of `fromLatin1()`.

With the precompiler flags `QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII` and `QT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII` it is possible to spot implicit conversions. But I don't want to refactor my huge project to support Utf8, I'm totally fine with Latin1 encoding.

How can I get the `QString` constructor work like before in Qt4? Is there a alternative to `QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings` which was available in Qt4?

Comment: (Of course it is your task, but... there is 2015, windows supports utf8 since 20 years ago, maybe would you consider a complete migration to the wonderful world of the unicode?)